# Get plus(+) operator from C# controller as string

Tags: c#, typescript, operators

I need to send a plus(+) operator as string from typescript service to C# Controller. When I debug it, typescript sends as "+", but in C# Controller, the parameter comes as null. The equal sign or negative sign(=,-) are working fine. Just plus sign has a problem. For example if I try to send "13+" plus is recognized as a blank -> "13 " in controller How can I solve it?

Comment: You likely need to post your typescript code and how you send the request. Possibly due to not escaping the query parameter correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` means space in an URL, so I'm assuming you're assembling an url query string by hand? If so, you need to encode `+` to `%2B`.

Comment: I wondered if I could get it directly as "+" from controller. When I encode it controller gets it as %2b but I replaced it with "+" so that solved it. Thank you.